# Как прибавлять к ключу объекта + 1?

Tags: javascript

Здрасьте, тут (аудиоплеер) нужна функция которая меняет картинку композиций по очереди, типо прибавляет один. Как написать эту функция и можно если у ключа объекта наприм. cover1, cover2  с логикой  + 1 как то получить эту функцию.

```
let songs = [{
    name: 'TKN',
    src: './assets/songs/ROSALÍA, Travis Scott - TKN.mp3',
    cover1: './assets/images/rosalia-tkn.jpg',
    artist: 'ROSALÍA, Travis Scott',
    lyrics: ''
},{   
    name: 'No Heart',
    src: './assets/songs/21 Savage & Metro Boomin - No Heart.mp3',
    cover2: './assets/images/no-heart.jpg',
    artist: '21 Savage, Metro Boomin',     
    lyrics: ''
}];



let songIndex = 0;

function loadSong(song) {
  song_info.innerHTML = song;
  audio.src = songs.src;
  song_wrap = songs.cover; //index + 1
}

loadSong(song[songIndex]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К свойствам объекта можно обращаться не только с помощью точки. Можно использовать квадратные скобки, где можно составлять нужную строку, т.е. название свойства:

```js
let songs = [{
    name: 'TKN',
    src: './assets/songs/ROSALÍA, Travis Scott - TKN.mp3',
    cover1: './assets/images/rosalia-tkn.jpg',
    artist: 'ROSALÍA, Travis Scott',
    lyrics: ''
},{   
    name: 'No Heart',
    src: './assets/songs/21 Savage & Metro Boomin - No Heart.mp3',
    cover2: './assets/images/no-heart.jpg',
    artist: '21 Savage, Metro Boomin',     
    lyrics: ''
}];



let songIndex = 0;

function loadSong(song) {
  //song_info.innerHTML = song;
  //audio.src = songs.src;
  //song_wrap = songs[`cover${++songIndex}`]; //index + 1
  
  return song[`cover${++songIndex}`];
}

console.log(loadSong(songs[songIndex]));
console.log(loadSong(songs[songIndex]));
```

Comment: а куда ты тратишь то время, которое у тебя остается, когда ты вместо "свойствам" пишешь "св-ам" :-D

Comment: @Grundy Никуда Это привычка у меня с 6-ти лет универа осталась. Чтобы поспевать за лектором и записывать всё, мы стандартные слова писали сокращённо. Типа функция - это ф-ия, функционал - это ф-ал, количество - это кол-во, свойства - это св-ва, называется - это наз. ну и т.д. Это я ещё немного отвык от этой привычки :) Написал полностью, ради тебя :)

Comment: Замечаю, что много где стали писать сразу в "апострофах" текст с переменной, но в некоторых случаях мне кажется удобнее через плюс склеить) `'cover'+ ++songIndex`, ну в данном случае читается грязно из-за "инкремента" (забыл как называется, когда перед переменной)

Comment: @OliverPatterson субъективщина

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, согласен.

Comment: @EzioMercer а как также сделать но на jquery?

Comment: @Martin21 Что значит сделать также на jquery? Это просто ф-ия, которая работает с объектом, тут абсолютно нечего переводить на jquery